# Configure Ident Server on CentOS 7

Tags: centos

I am trying to figure out how to configure ident server on CentOS 7 but it looks like the ident package is no longer supported for CentOS 7. I don't want to install it from source due to some restrictions.

Is there any alternative package that runs ident server on CentOS 7?

Comment: On CentOS 7 you have authd daemon that would work as ident.

Answer (score 1):

Ident, pident and oident have been deprecated in favour of the [authd](https://fedorahosted.org/authd/) package. It features pretty much all of the features of pident while integrating nicely into systemd's socket activation framework.